# Create a document template with a required field blank

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to be able to have a required field be blank by default on a document template. Ideally, I would like to have the quickparts in there and the user would be able to start a new document, fill out the parts, and the required metadata would be updated from the user input. As of right now I am only able to use a template if I define a value for the field in the template.

Ideally, a user will create a document and put in their manager's name which would trigger a flow to email that manager when the document is added/saved. I have all of the parts working except that the manager's name field (which is required) that has to have a default value in the template. This means the same person would get the email for every single form submitted instead of the appropriate manager.

This is my first venture into sharepoint so please be gentle and ELI5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required field cannot be blank, you can use space " " if its a text field as the default value. But if you need this field blank at start, remove the "required" option.

You can in template add some admin email as default and in Flow check that the email is changed and after this send email.

Comment: Would there be a way to not require the field in Sharepoint, but have some sort of hard stop that would require them to change the default?

Comment: you can probably edit the newForm and add some verification on clientSide, but this isnt my work.

Answer (score 0):

Download the file and edit it locally, then upload the template again.

(To download a template, right click and "save as" on "Edit Template" link in Advanced Content Type settings)