# Workflow with sending email based on lookup

Tags: email, workflow-lookup

I have created a list with two lookup columns. Those columns are filled with an email address. Besides I have created a workflow to make an email sent if the list is saved, however now email is sent. I can see the email is returned as #name@company.com. Is there a way to resolve this? I have seen something about writing a code but I do not know how to get there?
Thank you
BR

Maybe I am in the wrong field as I see you are using a string as I am working in here? The field Hotelname:HD is the lookup field from another list:
[image]

Where do I have to go the second option, change the variable? I am not yet that familiar with SP, thx

Answer (score 0):

For the Flow problem, can you add here a screenshot? I tried it with SP Workflow 2010 and it works correctly. In WF use simply return field: `Lookup Value (as Text)`.

[image]

In Flow you can create Variable and in variable use expression `Replace('#','') or Replace("#","")` for the email input. It will work.

" or ' depends on environment location i think.

[image]

Comment: Please don't add the exact same answer to different questions. Either the questions are duplicate and should be merged, or the answer given should be different. See https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/256343/create-a-document-template-with-a-required-field-blank/256396#256396

Comment: what? i added this answer to another question, my mistake, i fixed it. I editet both answers and now it is correct.

Comment: Maybe I am in the wrong field as I see you are using a string as I am working in here? The field Hotelname:HD is the lookup field from another list: see added printscreen in the question

Comment: Oh, this is the added another field from the lookUp, this is not the base lookup, where you are selecting item, but the "more fields" option, right?

Comment: I have "Lookup for string" because i set string variable, try to use variables if the value will be correct, if not, check values in sharepoint fields for hotelname:HD